# WooCommerce Smart Coupon generated from which Item?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, coupon

I am writing a business extension (pdf printing) for the smart coupons.

Now I need a relation from the generated coupon (of the order) and the order item.

For example, which order item has generated the coupon?
Is there a way to get the order `item_id` from the coupon?

Is use this code to get the coupons:

`$coupons = get_post_meta($order_id, 'sc_coupon_receiver_details', true));`

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution, but i had to put the code inside "woocommerce-smart-coupons.php" file.

Line 379: Extend the Filter Variables

```
add_filter( 'generate_smart_coupon_action', array(  $this, 'generate_smart_coupon_action' ), 1, 10 );
```

Line 4783: Extend the Variable with the $item_id

```
if( $this->is_coupon_amount_pick_from_product_price( array( $coupon_title ) ) ) {
                                            $email_to_credit[$receivers_emails[$coupon->id][0]][] = $coupon->id . ':' . $sc_called_credit_details[$item_id] . ':' . $item_id;
                                        } else {
                                            $email_to_credit[$receivers_emails[$coupon->id][0]][] = $coupon->id . ':' . $coupon->amount . ':' . $item_id;
                                        }
```

Line 4816: Get the $item_id from the details and refer it to the "generate_smart_coupon" method

```
foreach ( $email_to_credit[$email_id] as $coupon_credit => $qty ) {
                        $coupon_details = explode( ':', $coupon_credit );
                        $coupon_title = get_the_title( $coupon_details[0] );
                        $coupon = new WC_Coupon( $coupon_title );
                        $credit_amount = $coupon_details[1];
                        $item_id = $coupon_details[2];
                        $message_index = array_search( $email_id, $email[$coupon->id], true );
                        if ( $message_index !== false && isset( $receivers_messages[$coupon->id][$message_index] ) && !empty( $receivers_messages[$coupon->id][$message_index] ) ) {
                            $message_from_sender = $receivers_messages[$coupon->id][$message_index];
                        } else {
                            $message_from_sender = '';
                        }
                        for ( $i = 0; $i < $qty; $i++ ) {
                            if ( $coupon->type != 'smart_coupon' ) continue;    // only process smart_coupon here, rest coupon will be processed by function update_coupon
                            $this->generate_smart_coupon( $email_id, $credit_amount, $order_id, $coupon, 'smart_coupon', $gift_certificate_receiver_name, $message_from_sender, $gift_certificate_sender_name, $gift_certificate_sender_email, $item_id );
                            $smart_coupon_codes = array();
                        }
                    }
```

Line 5194: Change the Method and extend the variables

```
public function generate_smart_coupon( $email, $amount, $order_id = '', $coupon = '', $discount_type = 'smart_coupon', $gift_certificate_receiver_name = '', $message_from_sender = '', $gift_certificate_sender_name = '', $gift_certificate_sender_email = '', $item_id = '' ) {
            return apply_filters( 'generate_smart_coupon_action', $email, $amount, $order_id, $coupon, $discount_type, $gift_certificate_receiver_name, $message_from_sender, $gift_certificate_sender_name, $gift_certificate_sender_email, $item_id );
        }
```

Line 5212: Extend the filter method to

```
public function generate_smart_coupon_action( $email, $amount, $order_id = '', $coupon = '', $discount_type = 'smart_coupon', $gift_certificate_receiver_name = '', $message_from_sender = '', $gift_certificate_sender_name = '', $gift_certificate_sender_email = '', $item_id = '' ) {
```

Line 5307: Store the $item_id in the post_meta

```
update_post_meta( $smart_coupon_id, 'apply_before_tax', $apply_before_tax  );
                update_post_meta( $smart_coupon_id, 'free_shipping', $free_shipping );
                update_post_meta( $smart_coupon_id, 'product_categories', $product_categories  );
                update_post_meta( $smart_coupon_id, 'exclude_product_categories', $exclude_product_categories );
                update_post_meta( $smart_coupon_id, 'generated_from_order_id', $order_id );
                update_post_meta( $smart_coupon_id, 'generated_from_item_id', $item_id );
```